# Customizing the export options template

Tags: org-export

Is it possible to customize the org mode export options template?

[12.1 Export options](https://orgmode.org/guide/Export-options.html#Export-options)

```
C-c C-e #

    Insert template with export options, see example below. 

#+TITLE:       the title to be shown
#+AUTHOR:      the author (default taken from user-full-name)
#+DATE:        a date, fixed, or an Org timestamp
#+EMAIL:       his/her email address (default from user-mail-address)
#+LANGUAGE:    language, e.g. ‘en’ (org-export-default-language)
#+OPTIONS:     H:2 num:t toc:t \n:nil ::t |:t ^:t f:t tex:t ...
```

Is there a way to do this that retains the dynamic fields (e.g. user-full-name, timestamp, user-mail-address, etc.) Implementing with easy templates or yasnippets is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with current org-mode. The idea is to remind you of all the options that are there, and allow you to keep/modify some and delete the rest. The template is filled in programmatically, including the replacement of what you call "dynamic" fields by their default values (but they are not really dynamic: the function `org-export-insert-default-template` fills in the template and then just inserts the resulting strings for each option in the buffer - you don't get a chance to fill it in).